# dropdownlist not showing on view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm passing `List<SelectListItem>` to the view via `ViewBag`. The dropdown for "Groups" appears but the "Organizations" label and drop down doesn't appear.

I want to show an empty dropdown control if the `viewbag` doesn't contain any groups/org.

What might be happening that's not making the 2nd label and dropdown appear?

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Group)
</div>
@{
    var groupList = ViewBag.Group as List<Helpdesk.Models.GroupModel>;

    if (groupList != null && groupList.Count > 0)
    {
        var groupItems = new SelectList(groupList, "ID", "Name");

        <div class="dropdown-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Group.ID, @groupItems)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Group.ID)
        </div>                        
    }
    else { <select /> }                 
}
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Organization)
</div>
@{
    var orgList = ViewBag.OrgList as List<Helpdesk.Models.OrganizationsModel>;

    if (orgList != null && orgList.Count > 0)
    {
        var orgItems = new SelectList(orgList, "ID", "Name");

        <div class="dropdown-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Organization.ID, @orgItems)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Organization.ID)
        </div> 
    }
    else { <select /> }
}
```

Comment: Why you are using if else statement

Comment: to check if the viewbag is null or if it doesn't have any items

Comment: Add a breakpoint to the second part in the Razor view and debug it. Also check the resulting HTML as source, maybe the browser does not like a self closing select element without any contents.

Comment: You should be handling this in your controller action and create specific ViewModel properties for the dropdown values. See http://theminimalistdeveloper.com/2010/08/21/why-when-and-how-to-use-typed-views-and-viewmodel-pattern-in-asp-net-mvc/ for more details.

Comment: i used a different way to display the dropdown list but I never got to check why it skips the 2nd drop down list even using breakpoints. I'll check again later just to satisfy my curiosity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do this:

```
if (orgList != null && orgList.Count > 0)
{
    var orgItems = new SelectList(orgList, "ID", "Name");

    <div class="dropdown-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Organization.ID, @orgItems)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Organization.ID)
    </div> 
}
else { 
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Organization.ID, new SelectListItem[] { })
}
```

Push an empty array of items, instead of displaying an empty select element.

Comment: Actually putting <select /> on the else clause was easier, thanks for the suggestion, but this doesn't explain why the 2nd drop down wasn't showing.